# Incomplete json response from php to iOS app

Tags: php, ios, json

In my iOS application i have an asynchronous connection that calls a php script on my server. This script makes a query to the database and give a response with json_encode.

This is the script:

```
$result = mysql_unbuffered_query($query);
if ($result){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    if($output!=null)       
        echo json_encode($output);
    else 
        echo "0";
}
```

All works good when the response is short, but when i have a long response (like 500 characters), i receive an incomplete json as this example:

```
[{"user":"1","password":"password","tel":"3333333333","description":"some text, some text, some text","data":"2013-10-13 09:53:54"}, {"user":"1","password":"password","tel":"3333333333","description":"some text, so
```

In my iOS application, i use this code to decode the json:

```
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

If i receive a full json all works good, else if i receive an incomplete json i send a new request. When json content is very very long, the json received is incomplete, but sometimes, after some requests, the response is good anyway.

/*** UPDATE QUESTION ***/

Perform request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:advertURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", query];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Get response:

```
//in NSURL method didReceiveResponse

ResponseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

//in NSURL method didReceiveData

[ResponseData appendData:data];

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:ResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:Responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if(!json){
    //incomplete json!
}
else{
    //good json!
}
```

Why this happen? How can i solve this?

Hope i explained myself, thank you.

Comment: Please post the code with which you perform the network request and receive the data.

Comment: @Rob you read my mind.

Comment: You should probably send the right http headers, like Content-Length and Content-Type

Comment: Ok, now i understand how NSURL didReceiveData method works. I have to put my last code in connectionDidFinishLoading method, when my variable responseData is full. Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is common when people use the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods (or the `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` methods), and don't realize that it may require multiple calls to `didReceiveData` to receive the entire payload.

So, what you can do is:

- instantiate a `NSMutableData` in `didReceiveResponse`;
- have `didReceiveData` only append data to the `NSMutableData`, recognizing that for larger payloads, it may take multiple calls to this method before all of the data is received; and
- in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` (if using `NSURLConnection`; if using `NSURLSession`, use the `URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` method), then proceed with the parsing now that all data has been received.